# How can I adapt this cheesecake recipe so that it doesn’t crack?

Tags: cheesecake

Below is the family cheesecake recipe.  It’s perfect, except for the crack that always happens during one of the cooling steps.  I’ve tried almost everything.  Water baths, eliminating the flour/starch, sliding a knife down the edges, using a “push” pan instead of a spring form, 8 hour cooking time at 200.  I even tried a sous vide version (don’t ask), no luck.  Any suggestions?

ETA: I always start with room temperature ingredients, and don’t over mix.  The eggs get added last, yolks pierced, and gently folded in.

- 1 lb cream cheese
- 1 lb ricotta
- 1 pint sour cream
- 4 eggs
- 1.5 cup sugar
- .25 lb salt butter
- 1.5 tbs lemon juice
- 1 tsp vanilla
- 3 tbs cornstarch
- 3 tbs flour

Bake for one hour at 350F.  Let cool to room temperature, then refrigerate

Comment: What cooling process do you use?

Comment: Over baking is a common cause of cracks. Have you tried Simple reducing the cooking time and/or temperature? Your oven could run slightly on the hot side making the recipe cook time be too long.

Comment: @AMtwo I’ve done 200 degrees for 8 hours.  With a massive amount of jiggle

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit : it looks like you've done most of the things recommended in [an older question about this problem](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/10766/67) ... but have you tried splitting up the cooking time?

Comment: Have you tried using an instant read thermometer to check internal temperature as well? Temperature will ultimately be more reliable than jiggliness, even though most recipes rely on time/jiggle rather than temp. It can also rule out overcooking, and help you focus on other aspects of method.

Comment: i bake it for 2/3rd of the time, then turn off the oven and keep it there until room temp. Then I broil if needed for color.